# Extract numbers from CVXPY array

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

I'm working on an optimization problem using Python's CVXPY package. I created a CVXPY variable called `x` (an array of 10 values). I need to impose a constraint that the 2nd largest value in `x` is smaller than .03. I tried converting it to a NumPy array to no avail. How do I extract values from the `x` array?

```
import cvxpy as cp

x = cp.Variable(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to stay within CVXPY, i.e. using the variable x directly.

The problem "*the second-largest x should be <= 0.03*" is not completely trivial.

The "*largest x should be <= 0.03*" is easy. It is the same as "*all x should be <= 0.03*" or

```
 x[i] <= 0.03 for all i
```

or in CVXPY notation:

```
 x <= 0.03
```

The second-largest condition means: all x must be <= 0.03 except for one. This can be modeled as (in math notation):

```
 x[i] <= 0.03 + δ[i]*(XUP-0.03)   for all i
 sum(δ[i]) = 1       (one exception) 
 x[i] <= XUP         (the constant XUP is an upper bound on x)
 δ[i] ∈ {0,1}        (binary variable)
```

I'll leave it up to you to transcribe this into CVXPY notation.